# Docusign Connect self signed cert no longer working

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, docusignapi

I have a Docusign Connect listener running on an EC2 instance. I setup SSL on this with a self signed certificate. This was working fine but I had to reboot my instance yesterday. After rebooting I updated the endpoint in my connect settings with the new DNS alias. Now I've started getting the below error in connect

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I double checked the cert settings were still setup the same in tomcat and they were. I also tried generating a new cert but no luck. I'm working on the demo environment at the moment which should work (and was working) with a self signed cert.

I can also access the SSL URL directly in the browser

Anyone come across this behavior before or have any thoughts on anything I need to change in my config to get it working again?

An update on this - I'm not actively looking into it but it looks to be a sporadic issue. Not sure if it's just a problem in the demo sandbox or not but having not touched the listener in 3 months some days I see the error and other days everything works as expected. I still haven't been able to find root cause but my guess is that the error message been shown is not the actual issue. Since sometimes it works and other times it doesn't, without changing any settings on the DS side or touching the listener or EC2 instance it's running on, I'm guessing there may be some kind of bandwidth or throttling going on in the demo sandbox. I haven't been able to confirm this though. Will add an update if I figure out what's going on.

Comment: Is anything getting logged in the Connect logs that might have some more info?  I.E. through Preferences -> Connect

Comment: Not much - this is the full error message - Error - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.; The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: What's really weird is doing nothing and coming back to this a month later it just worked... However I've been having the same problem sporadically the last 2 months when I've been asked to demo the POC which uses this... at this stage since it's a sporadic issue which occurs sometimes with the self-signed cert and not other times and I can't find root cause I'm looking for alternative solutions.